# decoding a block code in non systematic form

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, parity

I've a Generator matrix in Gf(2) in non systematic form( no seperate, data bits, and no separate parity). It is a full rank matrix. Now to find H[7x20] from this matrix I used the property G*H_transpose=Zero matrix[13x7]. I found 127 vectors  which are orthogonal to these 13 vectors.

out of these i have to pick 7 vectors, which constitute the H matrix. So i made use of the property, that R*H_transpose=0. (R is the codeword [1x20]). But i couldnt find any vector in the 127 vectors satisfying all the valid codewords.

From this it is evident that syndrome should not be zero for error free decoding. Now how to pick my vectors out of my 127 vectors..

Thanks.

Comment: If $c$ is a codeword then it is a linear combination of the rows of $G$. Hence for each $v_i$of the $127$ vectors you have found you necessarily have that $cv_i^T=0$. Maybe your $R$ is the received word, not a codeword.

Comment: BTW if you want to construct a parity check matrix, you just have to choose 7 vectors out of the 127, s.t. they are linearly independent over $\mathbb F_2$.